# What standard library function in C copys a zero byte to the stack?

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow

Which function in the C library copies the zero bytes(\x00) into the stack, leading to a buffer overflow?

Comment: Aside from the fact that it's not actually possible using the method you're describing, is there a reason you want to overrun the stack?

Comment: my input contain Zero byte and i want a function copying my input and does not boundary check for overwrite return address

Comment: You shuould update your question.  It sounds more like a question about copying an input stream into memory,  which is very different from what you've asked.

Comment: [`bzero`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bzero)?! Although it's not standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such standard function. C doesn't even specify that there should be a stack.

*If* you happen to be on a stack machine, and are willing to make assumptions about the stack's layout, you can certainly use `memset()` to write 0-bytes into stack memory.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` and `sprintf` copies a zero byte to the end of the buffer they use. This is why it is recommended to use `strncpy` and `snprintf`